# Read image from web MATLAB

Tags: excel, matlab, web, imread

I have to read an image whose web link is stored in a cell in an Excel sheet. So I extracted the raw data from the Excel sheet using

```
[num,txt,raw] = xlsread(file);
```

Then I converted the cell element `raw(10,2)` that contained the url of the image to a string using `url = char(raw(10,2))`.

Then I did `img = imread(url)` but it returns an error.

**Error using imread (line 349)
Can't read URL
"http://the-link-to-the-picture.jpg".**

What should I do?

Comment: If you type exactly the characters that in `url` in your browser, you get the picture page?

Comment: What about a url you know works in the browser, put that in your spreadsheet and run your code. Does it still fail? Then you know it's something to do with your conversion.

Comment: yeah, this was the url...
http://s3.datamonitor.com/pla/low/d7f00a4f-a943-4bd5-9470-b05933a7c5cd.jpg

It works in the browser.

Comment: @Sherlocked `img = imread('http://s3.datamonitor.com/pla/low/d7f00a4f-a943-4bd5-9470-b05933a7c5cd.jpg');` works for me

Comment: please upload some xls file so we can try.

Comment: Okay, I am having problems connecting MATLAB to the internet. I use a proxy, and despite entering the proxy host and proxy port in Preferences->Web in MATLAB, when I test the connection, it fails. Any ideas on this? I use the R2012b version.